# How to import entire three.js core library?

Tags: import, module, three.js

I don't know why my import statement `import * as THREE from 'three'` does not work: the html file opens to a blank screen.

Steps I have taken so far are:

I've `npm install --save three`

Somehow my code works if I link the js explicitly using `<script src='file path'></style??` but the import gives a blank page for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot:

[image: Screen shot here]

Also, what are the files under `three/examples` are they demo examples?

Thank you!!

Comment: You should read this about modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bare imports in websites. I suggest you replace the import statement with this:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.125.2/build/three.module.js';
```

For learning or tinkering using CDN URLs is totally fine. If you want to develop a real application, I recommend to work with a node workflow instead. Meaning you define your dependencies and project setup with `npm` and use a bundler for a build. Check out the following minimal project setup example using the ES6 modules of `three.js`.

https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm